# clean text in an edittext by pressing another edittext

Tags: android

I have a small problem with Edittext, I have two edittext and when I press an edittext the other must be cleaned, try to do it with isFocusable () but I can't, who can help me?

```
public void loadED(View view) {

        if (edt4.isFocusable()) {
            edt3.setText("");
        } else {
            if (edt3.isFocusable()) {
                edt4.setText("");
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Does *press an edittext* mean that the edittext is getting the focus?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `OnFocusChangeListener` applied to each EditText:

```
edt4.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            edt3.getText().clear();
        }
    }
});

edt3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            edt4.getText().clear();
        }
    }
});
```